# How to Write MultiCore multithreaded application?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, multicore

I have one application that is running in server and I want to use whole resource of that server. That is multicore server. And I need omulti thread design that use all memory and all core and run max to max thread at a time.

How Can I implement this multithreading. Please suggest me design and code id possible.

Thanks
Pankaj mishra

Answer (score 1):

You will have to please expplicitely mention more details. There can be a lot of factors:
1) If its a pure computational job, then it is believed to have the maximum (# of cores +1) threads working.
2) If it has I/O, synchronization, then you need to jot down how frequent it is and then accordingly scale it.

Search Amdahl's law. Which says that you cant increase the productivity after a mark even if you increase the number of cores.
In general it can depend on a lot of factors